# Alternate reading as char* and wchar_t*

Tags: c++, id3, wchar-t

I'm trying to write a program that parses ID3 tags, for educational purposes (so please explain in depth, as I'm trying to learn). So far I've had great success, but stuck on an encoding issue.

When reading the mp3 file, the default encoding for all text is ISO-8859-1. All header info (frame IDs etc) can be read in that encoding.

This is how I've done it:

```
ifstream mp3File("../myfile.mp3");
mp3File.read(mp3Header, 10);  // char mp3Header[10];

// .... Parsing the header

// After reading the main header, we get into the individual frames.
// Read the first 10 bytes from buffer, get size and then read data 
char encoding[1]; 
while(1){
    char frameHeader[10] = {0};
    mp3File.read(frameHeader, 10);
    ID3Frame frame(frameHeader);  // Parses frameHeader 
    if (frame.frameId[0] == 'T'){ // Text Information Frame
        mp3File.read(encoding, 1); // Get encoding
        if (encoding[0] == 1){
            // We're dealing with UCS-2 encoded Unicode with BOM
            char data[frame.size];
            mp3File.read(data, frame.size);
        }
    }
}
```

This is bad code, because `data` is a `char*`, its' inside should look like this (converted undisplayable chars to int):

```
char = [0xFF, 0xFE, C, 0, r, 0, a, 0, z, 0, y, 0]
```

Two questions:

1. What are the first two bytes? - Answered.
2. How can I read wchar_t from my already open file? And then get back to reading the rest of it?

Edit Clarification: I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do it, but essentially what I wanted to do was.. Read the first 11 bytes to a char array (header+encoding), then the next 12 bytes to a wchar_t array (the name of the song), and then the next 10 bytes to a char array (the next header). Is that possible?

Comment: The two first bytes look like an UTF-16 byte order mark, BOM. The rest is consistent with an UTF-16 encoding. UCS2 is a subset of UTF-16, and the comment in the code does say "UCS-2 encoded Unicode with BOM"; how did you produce that code without being aware of what that means?

Comment: I will look at this after you write that code in a format recognized by anybody. Just why.

Comment: Are you missing a line with `}` in the middle of that code?

Comment: Yes there definitely is a missing `}`

Comment: Corrected now, my bad!

Comment: Answer the other questions @AlexOsheter

Comment: Not entirely sure I understand the question.. @Cheersandhth.-Alf

I wrote the code based off the ID3 documentation, I know what kind of data I'm expecting, but purely on a logical level. I have no experience with Unicode on C++.

Comment: Unicode BOM: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: You edited this to add `char encoding[1];` inside the while loop. Take that out, you don't want to create a variable every time in the while loop. Put it at the top.

Comment: Edited. But how is it different from ```frameHeader[10]``` I always create?

Did you read my clarification regarding question 2? Is this the correct way to do it? If so, how can this be done? If not, what's the correct way?

Comment: @CoreyLakey: There's no cost associated with having the variable in the loop. You can look at the assembly to confirm what I'm saying. However, there is a code reading cost in using a size 1 array. A `char` variable on its own is all that's needed.

Comment: Didnt mean theres a cost, just bad practice.

Comment: @AlexOsheter: Given the data you present it looks like **big-endian** UTF-16. Your system is not necessarily big-endian (e.g. Windows runs on little-endian architectures such as the ordinary PC). This means you have two issues when you convert to `wchar_t` sequence, namely: (1) skipping the BOM, and (2) using some means of converting to the host byte order. Unfortunately the C++ standard library offers no way to detect byte order at compile time.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Big-endian? On the linked wiki page, it says that `if the 16-bit units use little-endian order, the sequence of bytes will have 0xFF followed by 0xFE`. My first byte was -1 (signed). `(uint8_t) -1 == 255`, second was 254.  255 is 0xFF, no?

Comment: @AlexOsheter: Sorry, you're right. My bad. Mea culpa. It's little-endian all right. Still you may want to consider whether the code will be used on big-endian system.

Comment: Are you doing this on Windows?

Comment: @BarmakShemirani Yes. Why?

Comment: Windows has `WideCharToMultiByte` and `MultiByteToWideChar` for this purpose.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani wow that's awesome. Thank you! I'll keep that in mind next time.

Comment: Actually I don't think you need `MultiByteToWideChar` here.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a decent solution: create a new wchar_t buffer and add the characters from the char array in pairs.

```
wchar_t* charToWChar(char* cArray, int len) {
    char wideChar[2];
    wchar_t wideCharW;
    wchar_t *wArray = (wchar_t *) malloc(sizeof(wchar_t) * len / 2);
    int counter = 0;
    int endian = BIGENDIAN;

    // Check endianness
    if ((uint8_t) cArray[0] == 255 && (uint8_t) cArray[1] == 254)
        endian = LITTLEENDIAN;
    else if ((uint8_t) cArray[1] == 255 && (uint8_t) cArray[0] == 254)
        endian = BIGENDIAN;

    for (int j = 2; j < len; j+=2){
        switch (endian){
            case LITTLEENDIAN: {wideChar[0] = cArray[j]; wideChar[1] = cArray[j + 1];} break;
            default:
            case BIGENDIAN: {wideChar[1] = cArray[j]; wideChar[0] = cArray[j + 1];} break;
        }

        wideCharW = (uint16_t)((uint8_t)wideChar[1] << 8 | (uint8_t)wideChar[0]);
        wArray[counter] = wideCharW;
        counter++;
    }
    wArray[counter] = '\0';
    return wArray;
}
```

Usage:

```
    if (encoding[0] == 1){
        // We're dealing with UCS-2 encoded Unicode with BOM
        char data[frame.size];
        mp3File.read(data, frame.size);
        wcout << charToWChar(data, frame.size) << endl;
    }
```

Comment: Your solution may work for English and other Latin languages only. UCS-2 and UTF-16 are different. UCS-2 is outdated. UTF-8 and UTF-16 are supposed to handle all languages.

Comment: I've tested it with English, Hebrew, Russian and Simplified Chinese. Works well. Also, there's not much I can do, seeing as some ID3v2 tags are encoded this way.

Comment: That's odd! It must be UCS-2 then.

Comment: I think your code will work for either UCS-2 or UTF-16 (in this specific usage), but you can shorten it.